# Javascript: find longest word in a string

Tags: javascript

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            longest = str[i].length;
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

When I call `longestWord("Pride and Prejudice")`, it returns 'Pride' and not 'Prejudice' which is the longest word... why? I checked some other similar questions, but the solutions looked a lot like my code.

Comment: don't name an array of strings `str`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because you're not comparing all the items in the array, you leave out the last one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++)
```

should be

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i <= str.length - 1; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks! The second solution is what I was trying to do, but I missed out the equal sign.

Comment: I would personally recommend the first solution for readability to others. The second one takes longer to write and would be less efficient if not for compiler optimizations (recalculating str.length-1 each time, but compilers don't do dumb things like that these days) so real world code would not use the second solution, in my experience.

Comment: @coder543, it *must* recompute each iteration because `.length` could be an accessor that changes. It's a fast operation though.

Comment: Mathematically, the the two are equivalent. i < x is the same as i <= x - 1, so a compiler could optimize that if it has an optimization pass for it.

Answer (score 14):

One advantage to taking a functional approach to such problems is that you don't even have to keep count

See [MDN Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for more info. (note: `reduce` needs shim for IE8)

```js
function longer(champ, contender) {
  return (contender.length > champ.length) ? contender : champ;
}

function longestWord(str) {
  var words = str.split(' ');
  return words.reduce(longer);
}

console.log(longestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs"));
```

Answer (score 5):

Here this is your solution with a forEach, this will help you avoid the error in the future

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    str.forEach(function(str) {
        if (longest < str.length) {
            longest = str.length;
            word = str;
        }
    });
    return word;
}
console.log(longestWord("pride and prejudice"));
```

Your original problem was just the `str.length - 1` should have just been `str.length`, originally you wouldn't have gotten to the last element of the array

Answer (score 4):

You have a `-1` in your condition, it never even scans it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
```

Should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LfgFk/

Answer (score 3):

The index is going up to `str.length -1`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++) {
```

So the **last word is not processed**.

Try with: `longestWord("Pride AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA and Prejudice")`. You'll see it works (returns `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA`).

In case you're in doubt, the simplest way to fix it is removing the `-1` from the `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
```

Check a demo with both versions (the problematic and the fixed): [link here](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/VwTNA/3/).

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code with a library like [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/):

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var words = string.split(' ');
    return _.max(words, function(word) { return word.length; });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ForEach is faster in FF but slower in Chrome,
but for loop with the cached length and function apply/call is quite faster in both FF and chrome.

Hope the below code  helps:

```
function getLongest (arrStr) {
  var longest = 0, word;

  for(var i=0 , len = arrStr.length ; i < len ; i++){

    if(longest < arrStr[i].length) {
       longest = arrStr[i].length;
       word = arrStr[i];
    }

  }

  return word;
}

function isLongest (str) {
  var arrayStr = str.split(' ');
  return function(fn) {
    return fn.apply(this,[arrayStr]);
  }
}

isLongest("hello aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbb")(getLongest); //aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++)
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i <= str.length - 1; i++)
```

*OR*

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

does this solve the problem??

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    for (var i = 0; i <= str.length - 1; i++) {
        if (longest < str[i].length) {
            longest = str[i].length;
            word = str[i];
        }
    }
    return word;
}

document.write(longestWord("pride and prejudice"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function longestWord(sentence){
 var arr = sentence.match(/[a-z]+/gi);
 arr.sort(function(a, b){
 return b.length - a.length;
});
 return arr[0];
}
longestWord('hello man@#$%');
// ==> output: hello
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that the .map method here helps a lot (this is if you want the character count of the word, not the word itself):

```
 function findLongestWord(str) {   
   var array = str.split(/\s+/);
   var wordLength = array.map(function(i) {
     return i.length;                       
   });   
   var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, wordLength);   
   return largest; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will refer you to [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/three-ways-to-find-the-longest-word-in-a-string-in-javascript-a2fb04c9757c) awesome article which defines three ways:

1 - Find the Longest Word With a FOR Loop

```
    function findLongestWord(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split(' ');
  var longestWord = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
    if(strSplit[i].length > longestWord){
    longestWord = strSplit[i].length;
     }
  }
  return longestWord;
}
findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

2 - Find the Longest Word With the sort() Method

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longestWord = str.split(' ').sort(function(a, b) { return b.length - a.length; });
  return longestWord[0].length;
}
findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

3 - Find the Longest Word With the reduce() Method

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longestWord = str.split(' ').reduce(function(longest, currentWord) {
    return currentWord.length > longest.length ? currentWord : longest;
  }, "");
  return longestWord.length;
}
findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Of course, it returns the length of the biggest word if you want to get the string, just get rid of the length in return part.

Answer (score 1):

```
function LongestWord(sen) { 

  // code goes here  
  const wordsArray = sen.split('').map(c => (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c<='9')? c : ' ').join('').split(' ').filter(item => item !== '');
  wordsArray.sort((a, b) => a.length < b.length);
  return wordsArray[0]; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For error checking in question, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17386797/15811844)

## Longest word in String

### Using for/forEach loop

```
function longestWord(str){
  const words = str.split(' ');
  let longWord = "";
  words.forEach((word) => {
    if(word.length > longWord.length) { longWord = word }
  })
  return longWord;
}
```

### Using sort

```
function longestWord(str) {
  return str.split(' ')
            .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];
}
```

### Using reduce

```
function longestWord(str){
  return str.split(' ')
            .reduce((maxWord, curWord) => curWord.length > maxWord.length ? curWord : maxWord );
}
```

```js
// for loop
function longestWord1(str){
    const words = str.split(' ');
    let longWord = "";
    words.forEach((word) => {
      if(word.length > longWord.length) { longWord = word }
    })
    return longWord;
}

// sort
function longestWord2(str) {
    return str.split(' ').sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];
}
    
// reduce
function longestWord3(str){
    return str.split(' ').reduce((maxWord, curWord) => curWord.length > maxWord.length ? curWord : maxWord );
}

let text;
text = "What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology";
console.log(longestWord1(text));//=> "otorhinolaryngology"
text = "";
console.log(longestWord2(text));//=> ""
text = "What "
console.log(longestWord3(text));//=> "What"
text = "What is pen?"
console.log(longestWord1(text));//=> "What"
text = "three four five six twenty one"
console.log(longestWord2(text));//=> "twenty"
text = ("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog")
console.log(longestWord3(text));//=> "jumped"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++)
```

isn't

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.length - 1; i++)
```

That seems like it could be the cause.

Comment: @aaronman LOL. Since the answer's been accepted I won't edit it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
for (var i=0;i<=str.length - 1; i++)
```

That way it will scan the entire phrase

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, this is the fixed code:

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var checkedLetters = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < str[i].length; j++) {
            if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(str[i][j])) {
                checkedLetters += str[i][j];
            }
        if (longest < checkedLetters.length) {
            longest = checkedLetters.length;
            word = checkedLetters;
            }
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the easiest way to do this.

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    var word = null;

    str.forEach(function(str) {
        if (longest < str.length) {
            longest = str.length;
            word = str;
        }
    });

return word;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would say using the forEach loop is the most understandable version

```
function longestWord(sen) {
  big_word = ""
  words = sen.split(" ")
  words.forEach(function(word){
    if (word.length > big_word.length){
        big_word = word
    };
  });
return big_word
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more easy

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
    var longestStr = 0;
    for (var x=0;x<str.split(' ').length;x++){
        if (longestStr < str.split(' ')[x].length){
            longestStr = str.split(' ')[x].length;
        }
    }
    return longestStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one other way to solve it.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var result = [];
  
  var one = str.split(" ");
    
   for (var i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
    result[i] = one[i].length;
     result.reverse().sort(function(a,b) {
       return b-a;
     });   
   }
  return result[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the sort() method,this sorts the elements of an array by some ordering criterion and then returns the length of the first element of this array and hence the longest word.

```
function longest(string){
    var longestWord = string.split(' ').sort(function(a,b){
        return b.length - a.length;
    });
    return longestWord[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
 function longest(string) {
        var str = string.split(" ");
        var longest = 0;
        var word = null;
        for (var i = 0; i <= str.length - 1; i++) {
            if (longest < str[i].length) {
                longest = str[i].length;
                word = str[i];
            }
        }
        return word;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is by using sort:

```
    function longestWord(string) {
        let longest = 0;
        let str = str.split(" ").sort((word1,word2)=>{
        });
        return str[0].length;
   }
   longestWord('I love Python ')
```

Comment: While this might be a viable solution a sort might take much longer than one iteration over an array.

Answer (score 0):

Code below will find the largest word and its length from a string.
Code is in plain JavaScript and html.

```js
function findLongestWord() {
  var str = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  calculateLength(str);
}

function calculateLength(str) {
  var substring = str.split(" ");
  var minChar = '';
  for (var i = 0; i <= substring.length - 1; i++) {
    if (substring[i].length >= minChar.length) {
      minChar = substring[i];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('longChar').innerHTML = 'Longest Word: ' + minChar;
  document.getElementById('longCharLength').innerHTML = 'Longest Word length: ' + minChar.length;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="inputText"> <br/>
  <button onclick=findLongestWord()>Click to find longest              word</button> <br/>
  <div id="longChar"></div> <br/>
  <div id="longCharLength"></div>
</body>
<script src="longestWord.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function findLongestWord(str) {
       let stringArray = str.split(" ");
       stringArray.sort(function(a, b){
          return a.split('').length < b.split('').length;
       })
       return stringArray[0];
    }

    findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solutions above are incomplete. What if there r 2 or more words that have same length. here is a better solution:

```
longest = str => {
  let words = str.split(" ");
  let size = 0;
  let max = [""];

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > size) {
      size = words[i].length;
    }
    if (max[max.length - 1].length < words[i].length) {
      max = [];
      max.push(words[i]);
    } else {
      max = [...max, words[i]];
    }
  }
  return max;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sortNumber(a, b) {
return a - b;
}

function findLongestWordLength(str) {
var split = str.split(" ");
var arr=[];
for(var i=0;i<split.length;i++){
  arr.push(split[i].length);
  }
  arr.sort(sortNumber);
  console.log(arr[arr.length-1]);
  return(arr[arr.length-1]);
}

findLongestWordLength("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const longestWord = string =>
{
    stringArray = string.split(' ').sort(
        (a,b) => b.length - a.length)
    let longestArray= stringArray.filter( word => word.length === stringArray[0].length ) 
    if(longestArray.length === 1){
        console.log(longestArray[0])
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(longestArray)
    }
}
longestWord("Pride and Prejudice")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// My simple solution.

const findLongestWordLength = str => {
    let array = str.split(" ");
    let longest = 0;

    array.map(e => {
        if (e.length > longest) {
            longest = e.length;
        }
    })
    return longest;
}
```

Comment: Please give some description for further detail.

Answer (score 0):

fast & simple way to do this is

```js
let str = "This is longest word";
let longestWord ="";
str.trim().split(" ").map(word=> (word.length > longestWord.length) ? 
longestWord = word : longestWord)
console.log(longestWord)
```

It will also handles extra spaces at the start & end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Simple and short using `reduce`:

```js
title.split(" ").reduce((max, word) => Math.max(max, word.length), 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function longestWord(string) {
   var str = string.split(" ");
   var longest = 0;
   var word = null;
   for (var i=0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
      word = longest < str[i].length ? str[i].length : longest;
         word = str[i];
   }
   return word;
   }
   longestWord('I love Python ')
```

Comment: this suffers of the same problem as the question. This is no challenge to give all possible to solutions to a problem but to help OP with his wrong code.

Answer (score -2):

Check if this helps:

```
function longestWord(string){
  var str = string.split(" ");
  var longest = 0;
  var word = null;
  for(var i=0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(longest < str[i].length){
      longest=str[i].length;
      word=str[i];
    }
  }
  return word;
}
```

Comment: This answers an old question (2013) when there is an already accepted answer which states the same thing as you have.