# "cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, split

I'm getting the following error:

> cannot read property 'split' of undefined

However the `array` variable with the `split` method attached is correctly defined in the previous code line.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {

  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var array = str.split(" ");
    array[i].split("");
  }
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: Do you want to iterate over each word, or do you want to iterate over each character? Figure that out, and then you can figure out which line you need to remove

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: `str.length` is 44. `array` has 9 elements. What do you think happens when you access `array[10]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: find longest word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386774/javascript-find-longest-word-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.length` is actually the number of letters in the string, while array is an array of words. That's why `i` can go up to 45, while your array has only 9 elements - that's why when it tries to access `array[10]` it gets undefined and it can't split it. This should help:

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var array = str.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].split("");
  }
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

If you want it to actually return the longest word, you need to do something like this:

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longestWord = ""
  var array = str.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i].length > longestWord.length){
      longestWord = array[i]
    }
  }
  return longestWord
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: Good answer. OP should also know that he hasn't quite gotten his function working yet, but this was an important step

Comment: @wassona, I was not able to get the output from above code.....were you?

Comment: @Mamun, the above code does not produce output. You'll need to put in a `return` statement somewhere to have output. The function, by the way, isn't quite finished, but you've made a good start. I'd throw some `console.log`s in there, in a few places, to track what's happening and what results you're getting, and think about what you can do to find the longest word from the results. Sorry if this is a bit frustrating, but I was a teacher for quite a while and like helping people enough so they can learn on their own.

Comment: @wassona, I even tried with returning `array` from the function but no expected output. I was interested in the answer because you stated the answer as "Good answer"....thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I could be more helpful. From your code, `array[i].split("");` is a good choice, but it isn't assigned to a variable, so that `.split` action is happening and then the result is immediately being thrown away. You should do something like `var wordLetters = array[i].split("");`. You can then use `.length` to figure out how many letters are in that word. All of the other solutions should work (though C. Sanchez leaves a step for you to figure out), but the way you're trying to solve the problem, though a little longer, is simpler, and, I think, a better intro to programming principles.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly apply [`split(" ")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method of array to get required result.

> The **reduce()** method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

**DEMO**

```js
const str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

let result = str.split(" ").reduce((r, v) => r.length > v.length ? r : v, '');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

str.length get the length of the string counting chars, so 44, then you do the split by spaces, so you get the words but you continue to call index of each char in the string, to get longest word instead of:

```
array[i].split("");
```

you must do:

```
var longest = "";
array.forEach(function(word) {
    if(word.length > longest.length) {
      longest = word;
    }
});
```