# Why doesn't the second code work the same as the first code?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function

> The First Code works correctly and displays the right answer which is 19.

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let high = 0;
  let word = str.split(" ");
  
  for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++)
  {
   if (word[i].length > high)
      high = word[i].length;
  }
  console.log(high)
}

findLongestWordLength("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology");
```

> The second code below, only works until the word "super-long" and logs **10** as the final output, which is incorrect. I'm trying to figure out what goes wrong here. It works fine with other sentences,

**FOR REFERENCE**

*The str.length in the sentence is 60(spaces included), and there are 9 spaces in between the entire sentence*

```
function findLongestWordLength(str) {
  let high = 0;
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] != " ") {
      count++;
    } else {
      if (count >= high)
        high = count;
      count = 0;
    }
  }
  return high;
}
findLongestWordLength("What if we try a super-long word such as otorhinolaryngology");
```

Comment: there is definitely something wrong with the second snippet, the number of `{` and `}` does not match. generally I would recommend to fix the indentation and always use braces for `if`-blocks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: find longest word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386774/javascript-find-longest-word-in-a-string)

Comment: Assuming a sane correction to the missing braces, you're just not checking the final word, because it is not followed by a space, and you are only checking for word length when encountering a space.

Comment: @Pixelmo: Why do you say that?  It looks like a mistake a programmer might legitimately make.

Comment: @Pixelomo, I think OP is trying to understand "why?" the algorithm doesn't work. This question doesn't deal with the same issue, so I don't think it answers OP's question.

Comment: What did you find out while debugging the failing example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get 19, you have to end your string with a space. Because the last character of `"otorhinolaryngology"` is a `'y'`, you simply increment count at the very end and you never hit your `else` condition which will update high. Put a space at the end, add an extra condition checking if `i == str.length -1` Or simply use the length algorithm, or, as I would prefer, use a reducer like so:

```js
const findLongestWordLength = str => str.split(' ').reduce((acc, word) => word.length > acc ? word.length : acc, 0)
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer I’m looking for, thanks a lot.

Comment: So if I was to add ` else if (str[i] == str.length - 1 || str[i] == ‘ ‘) ` and follow it with the “else”code, it would work correctly right?

Comment: Also I’m new to JS so I’m sorry if my code and method of thinking is a bit too basic, but thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but the you should accept the other answer because it just adds one condition at the end, so you don't have to muck about it `else if` , but yes, you can do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

`count` could be holding a non-zero value at the end of the loop, which will get ignored. Just add a check at the end of the loop as well to update that value.

```js
for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
  {
    if (str[i] != " ") count++;
    else 
    {
      if(count >= high) high = count;
      count = 0;
    }
  }
if(count >= high) high = count;
```